# About Android SDK add-on development

Tags: android, sdk, add-on

I am trying to develop my own Android SDK add-on. As I haven't been very successful in my Google searches, would someone kindly provide some information on this?

In addition, in what situation does an add-on generate a system image, and when does it not?  I've found that some official add-ons have their own images (like Motorola add-ons) while others use the default system image.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is looking at the source code of the android SDK itself, it's distributed within the Android source code and it contains everything from the SDK to the Eclipse plugin and you can access every piece of code from the source; i don't think that you will find a doc about it or a better source.